# Importing Python package (pandas) from R with Reticulate

Tags: python, r, rstudio, reticulate

Context: I was using Python on Atom IDE and installing/importing packages is working normally. Now I would like to work with Python on Rstudio through Reticulate package.

Problem: I'm not able to import Pandas on Rstudio even though a can Import numpy and math. The error is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'".

i) Python 3.8.5 installed (32 bit)
ii) pip3 21.1.2 installed
iii) Reticulate 1.2.0 installed
iv) Pandas is already installed (~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have many Python environments.

Check `reticulate::py_module_available("pandas")`.

And, if neccesary, `reticulate::py_install("pandas")`.

Comment: reticulate::py_install("pandas") worked. But why the installation through pip3 isn't being considered, as I already had installed Pandas using pip3?

Comment: They are different folders (different environments). `reticulate` needs its own installation.

Answer (score 0):

What does your code block look like for instantiating reticulate?

Here is mine; you should get into the habit of using environments as they will ensure all your packages are there and exactly the version you want.

```
# load python
library(reticulate)
use_python('C:/Users/Andrew/Anaconda3/')
use_condaenv(condaenv='my_ml', required=TRUE)
library(knitr)
```